# CURL SFTP support with Windows SChannel?

Tags: c++, ssl, curl, openssl, schannel

I'm working on shrinking an executable's size and a big saving was replacing **OpenSSL/Libssh** for **curl** with the windows standard **SChannel** (DLL on all windows machines)

This works correctly and has the SSL support for some things, but curl is unable to do SFTP with SChannel (unless I'm misconfiguring). I tried adding back LibSSH to curl to handle SFTP but that has a reliance on OpenSSL.

Is there any way to use curl/Schannel while maintaining SFTP functionality?

---

### Conclusion

Ended up building curl with LibSSH2 which can use a Windows DLL instead of OpenSSL, removing the need for OpenSSL at all.

Comment: You can make curl use libssh2 for SFTP, and libssh2 itself can be made to use wincrypt for the crypto (I believe) instead of OpenSSL...

Comment: @DanielStenberg Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibSSH relies on OpenSSL. LibSSH is needed for SSH functionality which itself is needed for SFTP functionality. SChannel does not provide SSH functionality and LibSSH cannot use SChannel. In other words: there is no way to get rid of any of these if you want to have SFTP functionality.

Comment: That's what I thought. So if SSH is required then there's really no reason to build Curl with anything other than OpenSSL? I know Cur; has other alternative libraries but I'm assuming LibSSH will only work with OpenSSL here.

Comment: @Prodigle: as I said, LibSSH requires OpenSSL. See also [INSTALL](https://git.libssh.org/projects/libssh.git/tree/INSTALL) in the libssh source code.